# Two definitions of integral on boundary $\int_{\partial\Omega}f$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have seen two definitions of an integral of a function $f:\partial\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ from the boundary of an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where the domain is Lipschitz.

1) 
$$\int_{\partial \Omega}fdS = \sum_i\int_{D_i}f(x_1,...,x_{n-1}, \varphi_i(x_1,...,x_{n-1}))dx_1...dx_{n-1}$$
where $\varphi_i:D_i \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz and $\partial\Omega_i = \{ (x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, \varphi(x_1, ..., x_{n-1})\}$ is a portion of the boundary.

2)
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}fdS = \sum_i \int_{D_i}f(x_1,...,x_{n-1}, \varphi_i(x_1,...,x_{n-1}))\sqrt{1+|\nabla \varphi_i(x_1, ..., x_{n-1})|^2}dx_1...dx_{n-1}$$

(I think this is the form I saw, but can't be absolutely certain).

Why the differences?

Comment: I think the first definition is wrong.

Comment: Hmm. the first definition, according to a book (http://i.stack.imgur.com/9RgTR.png), appears to suggest that it is sensible..

Comment: @matt.x : you should mention the book in your link in your _question_ (not just in a comment) or else nearly everyone will instantly answer that the first definition is incorrect and the second one is correct.

Comment: @StefanSmith I just waznted to give a motivation for the first definition. I don't want to know about norms or anything, just the definition of the integral.

Answer (score 3):

If no context is given, the integral should be with respect to $n-1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\partial \Omega$.  Then version 1) is wrong and version 2) is correct.  Version 2) is often encountered in third-semester calculus class or so.  Version 1) fails to account for the "steepness" of the surface $x_n = \varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$.

In the link you give in a comment, it is shown how definition 1) can be used to define a norm on $W^{s,p}(\partial \Omega)$.  This may work, provided the graph of $\varphi$ is not too "steep", because in that event, using versions (1) and (2) might give you equivalent norms for $W^{s,p}(\partial \Omega)$.  Then version (1) has the advantage that it is obviously simpler.

But to answer your question itself, with no other context, (1) is wrong and (2) is correct.

Comment: I guess you meant "version 2) is correct.."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why in some books, they use partition of unity, whereas in others, the definition (2) I posted above is taken? I guess (2) is very standard as indicated by your answer.

Comment: @matt.x : since $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of an open set, if you partition $\partial \Omega$ into pieces $D_i$ where each $D_i$ is part of a surface of the form $x_n = \varphi_i(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})$, then $\|\nabla \varphi_i\|$ is going to approach infinity near the boundaries of each $D_i$ (think of a sphere, using two hemispheres, for example).  Even worse, for some $\Omega$, $\partial \Omega$ has pieces that are perpendicular to $\mathbf{e}_n$ (the unit vector in the $x_n$-direction), and those pieces cannot be written in the form $x_n = \varphi_i(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})$ at all...

Comment: ... (for example, think of a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with sides in the directions of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$.  Using a partition of unity, you can avoid these problems.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I guess then my formula above is wrong. i need to put in a partition of unity.

Comment: @matt.x : for certain $\Omega$, you might not absolutely need a partition of unity.  Even if $\|\nabla \varphi_i\|$ goes to $\infty$ near the boundary of some $D_i$, the integral given by 2) in your question still might exist.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently correct is only the second one, as for $f\equiv 1$ it gives the $(n-1)$-area of the boundary.